# Generate MPEG Transport stream from audio files only

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have set up a HLS server and asked it to listen to localhost on port 5555 with this command `mediastreamsegmenter -f /Library/WebSever/Documents/live 127.0.0.1`

I have found a command to create an input stream from a **video** file and send it to the `mediastreamsegmenter`, as follow :

```
ffmpeg 
-re -i video.m4v 
-vcodec copy 
-vbsf h264_mp4toannexb 
-acodec copy 
-f mpgets udp://127.0.0.1:5555
```

Which command (with appropriate flags) should I use to create an input stream from a **.aac** file and send it to the `mediastreamsegmenter`?

Comment: Can you try `ffmpeg -re -i video.m4v -i audio.aac -c copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpgets udp://127.0.0.1:5555`?

Comment: Why would I use `-i video.m4v` if I only have an audio file, i.e `audio.aac`?

Comment: I assumed that you wanted to merge the video with audio and then send it over network, my mistake.